# Report Charts on Service Console Layout

Tags: service-cloud-console, report-chart

I'm currently trying to add a report chart on the side bar of the account service console layout, but it is not appearing in the service console when I try going to the account record. The weird thing is it shows up on the detail page but not on the side bar component

Here are some screenshots, of how I've set it up.

Added the report charts on the side bar with fixed width and height.

[image: Step 1]

Then here's how it looks like in the service console layout, the report charts shows up in the detailed page but not on the side bar component. Take note that I've made sure that these are Summary or Matrix reports according to this salesforce release note regarding report charts on console layouts: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_console_report_chart_setup.htm

[image]

Am I missing a step or something for my report charts to show up on my console layout?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you've manually resized the sidebar to be below 150px in width?  I see it's set to 180px in the settings, but I'm wondering if the chart isn't showing because the sidebar isn't wide enough to display it.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I've already thought of that minimum size limit, that's why I've set the width manually to 180px, even did 50% width still nothing comes up.